# Tiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-aws

From the time I have upgraded the versions of my eks terraform script. I keep getting error after error.

currently I am stuck on this error:

> Error: Get http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts/tiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
>
> Error: Get http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/tiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused

The script is working fine and I can still use this with old version but I am trying to upgrade the cluster version .

**provider.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.region}"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.target_account_id}:role/terraform"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = ".kube_config.yaml"
  version = "~> 1.9"
}

provider "helm" {
  service_account = "${kubernetes_service_account.tiller.metadata.0.name}"
  namespace       = "${kubernetes_service_account.tiller.metadata.0.namespace}"


  kubernetes {
    config_path = ".kube_config.yaml"
  }
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {

  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket         = "${var.backend_config_bucket}"
    region         = "${var.backend_config_bucket_region}"
    key            = "${var.name}/${var.backend_config_tfstate_file_key}" # var.name == CLIENT
    role_arn       = "${var.backend_config_role_arn}"
    skip_region_validation = true
    dynamodb_table = "terraform_locks"
    encrypt        = "true"
  }
}
```

**kubernetes.tf**

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "tiller" {
  #depends_on = ["module.eks"]

  metadata {
    name      = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  automount_service_account_token = "true"
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "tiller" {
  depends_on = ["module.eks"]

  metadata {
    name = "tiller"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "cluster-admin"
  }

  subject {
    kind = "ServiceAccount"
    name = "tiller"

    api_group = ""
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}
```

terraform version: 0.12.12
eks module version: 6.0.2

Answer (score 3):

It means your `server:` entry in your `.kube_config.yml` is pointing to the wrong port (and perhaps even the wrong protocol, as normal kubernetes communication travels over `https` and is secured via mutual TLS authentication), or there is no longer a proxy that *was* listening on `localhost:80`, or perhaps the [`--insecure-port`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips) used to be `80` and is now `0` (as is strongly recommended)

Regrettably, without more specifics, no one can **guess** what the correct value was or should be changed to

Comment: It was working fine with old version. Could you let me know which script shall I post to get the error. I check the github issues as well. nothing is working for me.

Comment: It's not exactly a script we need, it's more contextual information: where did that `.kube_config.yml` come from? can anyone access your kubernetes cluster _at all_? is that terraform command being run on a master node? are you the only one who would be making changes to the system? the list of questions is almost endless, because we are not on your machine in order to know what changed

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there is a need to set up Kubernetes provider on your terraform configuration.
Something like this:

```
provider "kubernetes" { 
  config_path    = module.EKS_cluster.kubeconfig_filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I miss-configure credentials for terraform with cluster and when there is no access to the cluster. If you configure your kubectl / what ever you are using to authenticate, this should be solved.